# GStreamer video capture using USB web camera on macOS

Tags: macos, video, gstreamer

I'm working on developing **gstreamer** app on **macOS**. I succeeded to get video captures of *MacBook's inside camera.*

```
$ gst-launch-1.0 autovideosrc ! osxvideosink
```

However, I don't know how to get video captures from attached **USB camera**. I looked at properties of `autovideosrc` element and `wrappercamerabinsrc` element, but couldn't find the proper one to specify the devices while I can specify `device` property to `v4l2src`.

How can I get video stream from USB camera using gstreamer on macOS?

***Any help would be appreciated!***

Comment: I don't know anything about `gstreamer`, but I guess it will have similarities to `ffmpeg` and when you work with `ffmpeg` on a Mac, you need to know that Macs use `AVFoundation` and not `v4l2`. So, my guess is that you need to find something that starts with `av...` or maybe `avf...`. Not much help, I know, but maybe enough to get you started.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks! I made it!

Comment: Excellent - please add it as an answer so other folks can find it. Also, you can mark it as correct yourself and get some points. Good luck with your project!

Comment: @toshiya, what were you going to do the with the video stream, do you remember? Do you mean, just display the webcam, or do were you using the video in another app?

Answer (score 3):

Finally I found how to do it.

```
$ gst-launch-1.0 avfvideosrc device-index=1 ! osxvideosink
```

Thanks @MarkSetchell

Comment: I am not quite understand, but wonder to see if you have any experience on this:====>

gst-launch-1.0 avfvideosrc device-index=1 ! osxvideosink =====>


Invalid video capture device index

Comment: How do you enumerate the cameras to find out how many you have?

Answer (score 0):

`osxvideosink` didn't work for me. I used `autovideosink` instead.

```
gst-launch-1.0 avfvideosrc device-index=1 ! autovideosink
```

- Also, I found `device-index=0` didn't work. My external webcam was `device-index=1`, and my built-in laptop webcam was `device-index=2`.